# AngularJS: How to represent and save an object per row in a table form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to have a table form of `departments` in which there are limited number of departments, date of which is available. Out of all those departments some of departments need to be assigned to students and once that is done the form needs to be submitted. On submission, each row in the table needs to be added in a collection of `assignedDepartments` collection.

Following is how I need the `assignedDepartments` collection to look if two departments have been assigned:

```
var assignedDepartments= [
    { "name": "Rohit", "age": 24, "department": "Computer Science", "isAssigned": true}, 
    { "name": "Matt", "age": 23, "department": "Engineering Physics", "isAssigned": true},
    { "name": "Rubi", "age": 32, "department": "Humanity", "isAssigned": false}
]
```

The `departments` collection is available that I am using to iterate through using `ng-repeat`:

```
<form name="assignedDepartmentsForm">
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
             Name
        </th>
        <th>
             Age
        </th>
        <th>
             Department
        </th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="department in departments">
        <td>
              <input  type="text" ng-model="name" />
        </td>
        <td>
             <input  type="number" ng-model="age" />
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ department}}
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="isAssigned" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
<form>
```

Could somebody help me create a table form for `departments`  in which each row is represented and saved as an object on form submission.

Comment: So, you want to copy to result of the table into a separate array?

Comment: I only have one array with me that is `departments`. I want every department that has been checked and assigned to some student to be saved in another array. It is not important if departments that are not assigned to some student are not saved, so `{ "name": "Rubi", "age": 32, "department": "Humanity", "isAssigned": false}` could be skipped from the resulting array. Here `isAssigned` is `false`.  But every department that has been assigned should have its data persisted as an object in the resulting array.

Comment: something like this http://jsbin.com/zapemulece/1/edit?html,output ?

Comment: @cbass: You have almost nailed it. Thanks :). I basically had only departments name, like `var departments = ['Computer Science', "Enginerring Physics", "Humanity", "Electrical Engineering", "Mechanical"];` Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Am sorry, i didn't realize I the mistake when I posted the question. Have updated the post removing the `department.` for `name`, `age`, `isAssigned`.

Comment: cool, i'll update as an answer in a monute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Covert you array of string to an array of objects instead(like below). Then it will get easier for you to add more fields to the objects.

```
[
  {"department":'Computer Science'},
  {"department":'Engineering Physics'},
  {"department":'Humanity'}
]
```

You can now still use you html-code. You just have to tweak your controller.

```
function formCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.departments = angular.copy(data2);
  $scope.submit = function() {
  $scope.assignedDepartments = [];
     angular.forEach($scope.departments, function(d) {
        if (d.isAssigned) {
           $scope.assignedDepartments.push(d);
        }
     })
  }
  $scope.assignedDepartments = [];
}
```

Here's an code example for it: http://jsbin.com/pegonisale/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Will I have to manually convert the `departments` array of String to `departments` array of Object?

Comment: Looks like I just need to convert `data` to `data2` automatically somehow.

Comment: you dont need data. only data2, forgot to remove the original array. but, yes, you will somehow have to convert into array of objects.

Comment: Nothing happens when I click on the submit but I've got the trick. Will take it from here. Thanks :)